# htaccess routing with url parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

`enter code here` Hi I've the following code inside my htaccess file.

My wildcard subdomain routes to "mainfolder" - here i placed the htaccess file.

I've the following folders
"mainfolder"
"mainfolder/sub1"
"mainfolder/sub2"
etc.

Calling the subdomain - sub1.domain.com it should route to the subfolder "sub1" (subfolder=subdomain).

I tried to do it with this code

```
#Redirect to subdomainfolder if no special page is called
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1/index.html [L]

#Redirec to subdomainfolder if a special page is called
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain.com(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

The first rule works well, but if I add the second rule I receive a internal server error.

Whats wrong with this - how how I can change the first rule in this way, that it works with all url-parameters after .com - that was the reasons for me to add the second rule.

Hope I get help for this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of web hosts today provide an easy implemention for subdomain creation in their administration panels. You just need to to go there, choose you subdomain name, and then point it to a directory in your tree.

If you can't, then it will be a little more complicated (You will need to resolve that subdomain to your server ip, configure some virtual hosts ... etc) and you may not have enough privileges to do that (unless you are on a dedicated server).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1
```

LIke

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub1/(.*)$ http://sub1.example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sub1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If more understanding step wise then follow https://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirecting-from-subdirectory-to-subdomain-using-htaccess/

Comment: yes, ive not enough possibilities (dedicated server) to do it in a better way, so i have to come closer with htaccess. I trie your suggestion, but there is no new rewrite url: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=eb70c72f-ec68-5884-9eca-89775c62028d